# Filtering data frame based on date column but keeping the id's as a second filter

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame like this :

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 131 | 2023-09-06 08:14:01.455890 |
| 131 | 2023-08-07 14:12:20.724080 |
| 124 | 2023-09-08 14:12:20.724080 |
| 131 | 2023-07-09 14:12:23.647488 |
| 124 | 2023-09-03 14:12:20.724080 |

I have tried this  `filtered_df.sort_values(by=['date','ID'],ascending=False, inplace = True)`  but it doesn't take in consideration the id for some reason, i want to filter the data based on date but at the same time keep the ID's togheter , something like this :

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 131 | 2023-09-06 08:14:01.455890 |
| 131 | 2023-08-07 14:12:20.724080 |
| 131 | 2023-07-09 14:12:23.647488 |
| 124 | 2023-09-08 14:12:20.724080 |
| 124 | 2023-09-03 14:12:20.724080 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the IDs together, ID should be your **first** sorting key:

```
filtered_df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'date'],ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Sorted data:

```
    ID                        Date
0  131  2023-09-06 08:14:01.455890
1  131  2023-08-07 14:12:20.724080
3  131  2023-07-09 14:12:23.647488
2  124  2023-09-08 14:12:20.724080
4  124  2023-09-03 14:12:20.724080
```